# move buttons on maximizing and minimizing the WPF screen

Tags: c#, wpf

What I am trying to do is accounting system I have some stack panel with three buttons what and rectangle under them I want is when I am maximizing the screen the buttons still fixed at their position and the rectangle did not fit the whole screen

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="0,29,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1016" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Invioice" Height="90" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="250"/>
        <Button Content="Customer" Height="90" Margin="100,0,0,0" Width="250"/>
        <Button Content="Expenses" Height="90" Margin="100,0,0,0" Width="250"/>
</StackPanel>
<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="859"
           Margin="10,124,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="996"/>
```

Comment: Not clear what you want. You could use a [DockPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) with the `StackPanel` docked to the top or bottom and the `Rectangle` set to fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear, but you can do all what you want by using a `Grid` and `Grid.RowDefinitions` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`

in this example, this define the stackpanel to be on the top, and the rectangle always on the bottom and fit the windows

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="90" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Invioice" Height="90" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="250"/>
        <Button Content="Customer" Height="90" Margin="100,0,0,0" Width="250"/>
        <Button Content="Expenses" Height="90" Margin="100,0,0,0" Width="250"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" ClipToBounds="True"/>
</Grid>
```